# How to read multiple 'Set-Cookie' Headers using Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, fetch, fetch-api

This a re-post since my original "question-answer" were deleted in [this directly-related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204093/how-to-get-set-multiple-set-cookie-headers-using-fetch-api).

How do you read "merged" multi cookies from Fetch API, especially when containing Expiration dates ?

We tried with `request.headers.get('cookie').split(',')` where :

`Cookie: cookie1=value1; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 04 Aug 2020 19:45:53 GMT; HttpOnly, cookie2=value2; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 05 Sept 2020 14:32:03 GMT; HttpOnly`

... but obviously this fails because of the comma in the dates.

Context: i'm trying to promote native fetch to my teams currently using XMLHttpRequests, but they are reluctant because of this -very frequent- expires issue.

Comment: The dupes are from 2011 and 2012 but still applies

Comment: they don't applies at all (or did not find anything related - also fetch did not exist in 2011/2012)
i'm asking specifically about multi-cookies from fetch **containing dates with comma**

Comment: No, You ask about parsing a cookie. It should not  be comma delimited. You likely get a toString of an array or something.

Comment: What does `console.log(response.headers.get('set-cookie'))`  give you after you fetch with `{
      headers: {
        credentials: "include"
      }
    }`

Comment: As explained in previous thread, and explicitly stated here, parsing a multi-cookies from Fetch results in a single string with ALL cookies concatenated.
Thing i'm asking is how to parse/read in the particular case -and extremely frequent- where an expires date is set.
We are stuck with old fashioned XMLHttpRequest, i'm trying to promote fetch, but because of this issue, team is reluctant to hop-in.... in 2023 o.O

Comment: Ok. Using cookies in 2023 is also so 2001 ;) I have reopened the question

Comment: Also when browser is auto-setting all requests with Set-Cookie valueS from backend,
there are consequently only one single Cookie header (containing all subcookies concatenated) when backend receive any request, no "Set-Cookie"

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```js
const cookie =`cookie1=value1; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 04 Aug 2020 19:45:53 GMT; HttpOnly, cookie2=value2; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 05 Sept 2020 14:32:03 GMT; HttpOnly`;
const parts = [...cookie.matchAll(/(.*?); Path=(.*?); Expires=(.*?); HttpOnly,? ?/gm)]

parts.forEach(part => {
  const [_,keyVal,path,date] = part;
  console.log(keyVal.split("="))
})
```

Comment: At first glance yes (need to get mostly the expires value to  check validity)
... but actually might be fragile for example when cookie properties are unordered or missing ?

Comment: They are unlikely to be unordered. You can implement an increasingly complex parsing in this order: `name,value, expiry-time, domain, path, creation-time, last-access-time,
   persistent-flag, host-only-flag, secure-only-flag, and http-only-
   flag.`